# Visual Studio 2013 - Unrecognized Namespace in Markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

My VS2013 (using .NET 4.5) shows the weird error

```
Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'web'.
```

on every  Control of my page.

Here's how my web.config looks like:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="web" namespace="Customer.PL.App.Code" assembly="Customer.PL.App"/>
    <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
    <add tagPrefix="company" namespace="company.Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="company.Telerik.Web"/>
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/Code/UC/GridButtons.ascx" tagName="GridButtons"/>
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/Code/UC/REchteList.ascx" tagName="RechteList"/>

    <!-- Wizard User Controls -->
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/OM/UC/Auftragspositionen.ascx" tagName="UCAuftragspositionen"/>
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/OM/UC/Auftragsdaten.ascx" tagName="UCAuftragsdaten"/>
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/OM/UC/Lieferadresse.ascx" tagName="UCLieferadresse"/>
    <add tagPrefix="web" src="~/OM/UC/Vorschau.ascx" tagName="UCVorschau"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

I tried removing the other  Prefixes but it doesn't fix it.
It makes my intellisense crash and evertime I type

```
<web:
```

it autocompletes as

```
<asp:ProxyWebPartManager:
```

it's really annoying.

Note: Same error in VS2012. I even tried restarting the whole computer, but no change.

Edit: Something in the Stackoverflow formatting screwed my text. Somehow you can't write a tag like *< web:* (just without the space) outside a code block.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Visual Studio. Where is your page's code? Have you added references to all the dlls that use this prefix?

Comment: References are there, the project is working. If I add a new Control with an ID, I can use it in the Code-Behind File, which is why I'm assuming it' VS13 that does the mess. If a reference or dll would be missing, it shouldn't compile and run.

Comment: I tried to create a stupid test page - no Master-Page, no inheritance, just a simple _<web:Button runat="server"_ ID="btnTest" /> but it isn't recognizing the tag.

Comment: The <controls> section doesn't define any `Button` tagName. Unless `Customer.PL.App.Code.dll` contains a Button contorl, you probably meant `<asp:Button>`

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a clean project and make changes one at a time to see what went wrong? If you are trying to add a Telerik button, make sure you've [installed the controls](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-adding-to-vs-toolbox-net.html) properly

Comment: Nope, our `Custom.PL.App.dll` contains this Button - `public class Button : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button, ISkin`

Comment: Then add it to the Toolbox and add the button from the toolbox to ensure there is no problem with your control that prevents if from being used. Then check web.config and the page to see the proper configuration.